# DataTables with more tables on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to ask how can i use DataTables plugin with more tables generated by JavaScript code on one page. From three tables only two are rendered and in the wrong order.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbr9q45/1/)

```
var keywords1 = JSON.parse("{\"1\": [\"lor\"],\"2\": [\"ember\"],\"3\": [\"pleasant\"]}");
var keywords2 = JSON.parse("{\"1\": [\"bachelor\"],\"2\": [\"mber\"],\"3\": [\"pleasant\"]}");
var keywords3 = JSON.parse("{\"1\": [\"b\"],\"2\": [\"rem\"],\"3\": [\"pl\"]}");

    buildKeywordTableString(keywords1);
    buildKeywordTableString(keywords2);
    buildKeywordTableString(keywords3);


    function buildKeywordTableString(keywords){

    var keywordTableString = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>';

    var keys = Object.keys(keywords);
    var dataSet = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < keywords[keys[i]].length; j ++){
            var row = new Array();
            row.push(keywords[keys[i]][j]);
            row.push(keys[i]);
            dataSet.push(row);
        }
    }

    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Key" },
        { "title": "R" }
    ]
} );   

    document.body.innerHTML = keywordTableString + document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `buildKeywordTableString()` runs, it creates another table with `id="example"`, which is wrong because ids should be unique. It is uncertain which node `$('#example')` will find.

You can actually create and prepend a new table, and apply datatables to it without the need for an id.

```
function buildKeywordTableString(keywords) {
    var keys = Object.keys(keywords);
    var dataSet = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < keywords[keys[i]].length; j ++) {
            dataSet.push([
                keywords[keys[i]][j],
                keys[i]
            ]);
        }
    }
    $('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"></table>')
        .prependTo("body")
        .dataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "columns": [
                {"title": "Key"},
                {"title": "R"}
            ]
        });
}
```

That should at least give you a fighting chance.